# Random Numbers - Draw without replacement

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

`comList` is a list of strings (let us say 100), I want to draw eight strings out of the list randomly and save them into a new list. This is what I did.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()            

For i As Integer = 0 To 7
   _rndString.Add(comList.Item(rnd.Next(1, 8)))
Next
```

Looking into the new list is saw duplicates. That is since the `Random Class` draws with replacement.

Let us say I have 4 strings: `a,b,c,d` and I draw 3 randomly I can get the following resultset:

```
a,a,a
```

What is happening her. I draw `a` and `a` is put back into the pool of strings, so it is possible that I draw it again (shuffeling the pool doesnt help here since I still have a possibility to draw the same string). That is what rnd.Next(1,8) does, it draws a random number up to 8 but in the next draw you can draw it again.

I checked the `Random Class` but couldnt find a method for drawing without replacement. Does anyone knows if there is a Class in `.NET` that implements a drawing without replacement or how I can get this done?

Comment: Drawing without replacement is a [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), not a random number.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting it. The solution in the link is as follows: I have a Array with 5 items put this into the function and get back an array where the items are randomly sorted. Ok, but I have 100 strings and have to draw 7 and these 7 have to be drawn without replacement. I just dont see how the shuffling can help me.

Comment: Shuffle 100 strings. Draw 7. If that is not what you mean, edit your question to explain what you want, why a shuffle does not help and your question will be reopened.

Comment: ok, I revised my question.

Comment: What you are describing is shuffling, not `Random`, as posted before. Shuffling does help because it does not not “still have a possibility to draw the same string”; if that is what you are getting you are not shuffling. Please post your code.

Comment: Ah, I shuffle the 100 strings and just take the first 8 and get what I want. Sorry it is late! Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!